# Linux deleteing a folder's content

Tags: linux, find

I can `find ./ -type d -name "Debug" -exec rm -f {} +`  to delete the fold and content.

My question is: How to fine all "Debug" folders and ONLY delete the content and Not the folder?

Comment: Perhaps add a 'cd' into the folder before the 'rm -f'?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type d -name "Debug"  -print | xargs -I% find % -maxdepth 1 -type f -delete
```

- the first `find` lists all Debug directories
- `xargs` defines the "%" symbol as what is replaced by the received stdin.  You will often see `-I{}` for `xargs`, but I chose another string since you might need `{}` in the `find`.  Any char will do.
- the second `find`, in directory "%" (so here one of the Debug directories received from the first `find`), deletes all files under that directory.
- `-maxdepth 1` is used in the second `find` to make sure it only deletes the files in the current Debug directory, and does not recursively deletes all files.